# iOS App Localization: Storybords Translation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, localization

My storyboards appear to be translated when previewed in XCode but when I install the app on the device nothing is translated to other languages. Here is the checklist.

**Storyboards are all translated:**

[image]

**I have some duplicates here - perhaps the reason it is not working:**

[image]

**And finally local file structure on  my computer:**

[image]

**Question**: how to verify correct file linking or any steps to find the issue of Storyboards not working on the iPhone or Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Base.storyboard and other should be ##language##.strings. Inside these files you will translate things corresponding to ID of the element.

You can check explicitly if the string is translated by calling something like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString("AWO-r7-rD4.text",nil));
```

You should put instead of "AWO-r7-rD4.text" one of the IDs from Localizable.strings for storyboard.

For comparison:

I have Auth.storyboard, and it can be nested to: Auth.storyboard(Base), Auth.string(English), Auth.String(French).

One stupid thing: Have you changed regional settings in simulator settings?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just redid the whole project localization and I have a similar file structure as you describe: MyApp.storyboard(Base), MyApp.strings(English), MyApp.strings(French), etc. Translation can be confirmed in one of those strings files. But I still cannot see the translation on the device. Yes, language is set to whatever language I am testing. Thank you.

Comment: In addition, I can confirm that Localizable.strings appear to be translating well for me (anything within the code). But storyboard strings do not :(

Comment: OK, got it: I had to clean the project and uninstall the app. New installation worked